# VBA to sequentially number rows in column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I want to number sequentially all cells on sheet4 starting at A2 (starts at 0) for 26000 cells in the A column

I have been trying the get the below code to work but need help.

```
Sheet4.Range("A2") = 0
Sheet4.Range("A2").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
  Step:=1, Stop:=26000, Trend:=False
```

Any advice/ fixes?

Comment: Your code worked for me. What is it not doing for you?

Comment: @guitarthrower - Im not sure but I modified this a bit and it works now.  I had to add the activate command as the macro was not being run from the same sheet.Sheet4.Activate
                Sheet4.Range("A2:A26001").Select
                Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlDataSeriesLinear, Step:=1, Stop:=26000, Trend:=False